# "How to use the Close/Reopen votes queue" help articles need updated screenshots

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, user-interface, help-center

In the [How do I use the Close Votes queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-close) help article, the screenshots have been outdated.  Currently, the screenshots of the review queues show the old UI, and look like this:

[image]

But the design has been updated, so they should have something like this:

[image]

Comment: But this wasn’t released to the rest of the network yet. I believe the pages are universal so this change needs to be made after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help center article has been updated with a new screenshot reflecting the new UI

---

> how does close queue work?
> oh cool! it has a filter!
> updated screenshot